# Использование Qt-классов в MFC-приложении

Tags: c++, qt5, mfc

У меня есть проект использующий MFC. Для расширения функционала диалоговых окон я хотел бы использовать Qt Widget-ы. Не могли бы вы посоветовать мне литературу освещающую подобные вопросы? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Нужен конкретный вопрос. "Посоветовать литературу" слишком субъективный, для сборников литературы есть отдельные вопросы. Лучше укажите метки языка, версии Qt и приведите ваш код, который надо изменять конкретным образом

Comment: думаю, это можно сделать, но будет достаточно проблематично. Ведь Qt это фремворк, который будет за Вас управлять событиями и всем-всем. MFC  в принципе делает то же самое. Думаю, легче будет все переписать на Qt или на MFC.

Comment: @KoVadim К сожалению проект не новый и довольно большой, поэтому вопроса о переписывании целиком не стоит."проблематично" - не могли бы Вы немного описать логику того, каким образом я могу вывести, например диалоговое окно используя описанные здесь методы наследования https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Comment: все очень просто - exec - блокирующая функция. Поэтому, вместо нее, нужно будет вызывать processEvents в основном цикле Вашего приложения. Но вот только как им разобраться, где чьи сообщения... Я бы сразу отказывался от такой идеи. Этот Франкенштейн будет ужасен. Также не забывайте о плюс 10-20 мб к Вашему приложению.

Comment: @KoVadim По поводу замены функции exec. Если я правильно понимаю логику работы классов Qt (прошу поправить, если я не прав), то для работы объектов QWidgets необходимо некоторое окружение, которое создаётся объектом QApplication. QApplication::exec() - запускает очередь обработки сообщений приложения. Но если я уже использую MFC класс для запуска очереди сообщений,  то мне получается и не нужен QApplication::exec()? Или без неё QWidgets объекты совсем загрустят, ведь, например, никто не скажет им о событии MouseClick (ведь это QApplication распределяет сообщения по окнам, да?)

Comment: mfc очередь событий не знает ничего о Qt и наоборот. Поэтому, да, они "загрустят". Я поразмышлял над этим и похоже, что нужно брать MFC главным, а Qt ведомым и делать в MFC какой то "посредник", который будет подбрасывать в Qt цикл события.

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант - вынести отдельные диалоги в DLL, и написать их с использованием Qt.

[Пример](https://github.com/DmitrySokolov/example-qt-in-mfc). Строить - сначала `Dll` в Qt Creator (или в VS + Qt VS Tools), потом `App` в студии. Проекты - дефолтные MFC и Qt Widget App. И, соответственно, механизм обмена данными - простейший - через строки.

[image: Using Qt Widgets in MFC app]